# Radial Overexposure Fix Gradiant OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a camera and a lamp. 
The camera takes pictures automatically and the lamp is rigid.

Each of my pictures has a bright spot in the middle and is getting darker on the outside (linear).

Is there an easy way to darken the middle, or brighten the outside to accommodate this (preferably with a gradient)?

I am using OpenCV with the C++ API.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Take a blank picture lit by the lamp. Invert it and blur it to lose detail. Multiply the Lightness channel of your future images by some proportion of that image to account for the lighting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say what exactly you want to do without an example. However, let's assume the effect is exactly the same in all images and you want to apply the same transformation to each of them.

You say the effect is linear, and assume you want to make the center darker by let's say 20% and the pixel furthest from the center brighter by 20%. Let's further assume the optical center is in the center of the image (needn't be true in practice).

So you have an image `cv::Mat img;` you want to manipulate, and I assume it contains data of type CV_32F (if not float or double-valued, convert, can be more than one channel). You create another cv::Mat

```
//first, make a mask image to multiply the image with
cv::Mat mask = cv::Mat::zeros(img.rows,img.cols,CV_32F);

float maxdist = std::sqrt(img.rows*img.rows+img.cols*img.cols)/2;

cv::Point2f center(img.cols*0.5,img.rows*0.5);

for (int j=0;j<img.rows;++j)
    for (int i=0;i<img.cols;++i)
    {
         cv::Point2f p(i,j);
         cv::Point2f diff(p-center);
         float dist(std::sqrt(diff.dot(diff)));
         float factor(0.8+0.4*dist/maxdist);
         mask.at<float>(j,i) = factor;
    }

//apply the transformation, to as many images as you like
img = img.mul(mask);
```

This doesn't check for overflows, you may or may not want to do this afterwards. But from your question, it would be a simple way to do this.